# Why this runtime OpenGL error in VS 2012?

Tags: c, visual-c++, opengl, glew, freeglut

[The program](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/6E_example1_VC10.zip) builds successfully:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: 6E test, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  example1.cpp
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\Angel.h(65): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'const GLfloat'
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(698): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(699): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(700): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(721): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(723): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(726): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(742): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>  InitShader.cpp
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\Angel.h(65): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'const GLfloat'
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(698): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(699): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(700): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(721): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(723): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(726): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\niklas\downloads\6e_example1_vc10\6e test\code\mat.h(742): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'GLfloat', possible loss of data
1>..\CODE\InitShader.cpp(10): warning C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdio.h(218) : see declaration of 'fopen'
1>  Generating code
1>  Finished generating code
1>  6E test.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Niklas\Downloads\6E_example1_VC10\6E test\Release\6E test.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

But then it crashes at runtime:

```
C:\Users\Niklas\Downloads\6E_example1_VC10\6E test\Release\6E test.exe
 OpenGL >2.1 context requested but wglCreateContextAttribsARB is not available
Falling back to legacy context creation


'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Niklas\Downloads\6E_example1_VC10\6E test\Release\6E test.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Niklas\Downloads\6E_example1_VC10\6E test\Release\glew32.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Niklas\Downloads\6E_example1_VC10\6E test\Release\freeglut.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~2\McAfee\SITEAD~1\sahook.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'6E test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in 6E test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x7747BDA1 in 6E test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.
The program '[7868] 6E test.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Unhandled exception at 0x7747BDA1 in 6E test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.
```

What can be done? Can you help me debug it? The program is an example OpenGL C program that I build in Visual Studio 2012:

```
// Two-Dimensional Sierpinski Gasket       
// Generated using randomly selected vertices and bisection

#include "Angel.h"

const int NumPoints = 5000;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
init( void )
{

    vec2 points[NumPoints];

    // Specifiy the vertices for a triangle
    vec2 vertices[3] = {
        vec2( -1.0, -1.0 ), vec2( 0.0, 1.0 ), vec2( 1.0, -1.0 )
    };

    // Select an arbitrary initial point inside of the triangle
    points[0] = vec2( 0.25, 0.50 );

    // compute and store N-1 new points
    for ( int i = 1; i < NumPoints; ++i ) {
        int j = rand() % 3;   // pick a vertex at random

        // Compute the point halfway between the selected vertex
        //   and the previous point
        points[i] = ( points[i - 1] + vertices[j] ) / 2.0;
    }

    // Create a vertex array object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    // Create and initialize a buffer object
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader21.glsl", "fshader21.glsl" );
    glUseProgram( program );

    // Initialize the vertex position attribute from the vertex shader
    GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( loc );
    glVertexAttribPointer( loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
                           BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );

    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); // white background
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
display( void )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );     // clear the window
    glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, NumPoints );    // draw the points
    glFlush();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    switch ( key ) {
    case 033:
        exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
        break;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA );
    glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );

    // If you are using freeglut, the next two lines will check if 
    // the code is truly 3.2. Otherwise, comment them out

     glutInitContextVersion( 3, 1 );
     glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );

    glutCreateWindow( "Sierpinski Gasket" );




    glewInit();

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

How to debug?

### Update

It's the row `glutCreateWindow` that crashes the program, if I comment out like this then there will be no stacktrace but also no window:

```
int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA );
    glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );

    // If you are using freeglut, the next two lines will check if 
    // the code is truly 3.2. Otherwise, comment them out

     glutInitContextVersion( 3, 1 );
     glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );
     /*
    glutCreateWindow( "Sierpinski Gasket" );




    glewInit();

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );

    glutMainLoop();*/
    return 0;
}
```

### Update 2

The following builds in VS 2012 but there is a runtime exception when trying to run the program. I think it should work and I'm a newbie at linking together C++.

```
`// Two-Dimensional Sierpinski Gasket       
// Generated using randomly selected vertices and bisection

#include "Angel.h"

const int NumPoints = 5000;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
init( void )
{

    vec2 points[NumPoints];

    // Specifiy the vertices for a triangle
    vec2 vertices[3] = {
        vec2( -1.0, -1.0 ), vec2( 0.0, 1.0 ), vec2( 1.0, -1.0 )
    };

    // Select an arbitrary initial point inside of the triangle
    points[0] = vec2( 0.25, 0.50 );

    // compute and store N-1 new points
    for ( int i = 1; i < NumPoints; ++i ) {
        int j = rand() % 3;   // pick a vertex at random

        // Compute the point halfway between the selected vertex
        //   and the previous point
        points[i] = ( points[i - 1] + vertices[j] ) / 2.0;
    }

    // Create a vertex array object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    // Create and initialize a buffer object
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader21.glsl", "fshader21.glsl" );
    glUseProgram( program );

    // Initialize the vertex position attribute from the vertex shader
    GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( loc );
    glVertexAttribPointer( loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
                           BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );

    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); // white background
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
display( void )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );     // clear the window
    glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, NumPoints );    // draw the points
    glFlush();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    switch ( key ) {
    case 033:
        exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
        break;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA );
    glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );

    // If you are using freeglut, the next two lines will check if 
    // the code is truly 3.2. Otherwise, comment them out

     glutInitContextVersion( 3, 1 );
     glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );
      glutInitWindowPosition( 0, 0 );
    glutCreateWindow( "Sierpinski Gasket" );




    glewInit();

    init();

    //glutDisplayFunc( display );
    //glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

The `Angel.h` file is:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  --- Angel.h ---
//
//   The main header file for all examples from Angel 6th Edition
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef __ANGEL_H__
#define __ANGEL_H__

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 
// --- Include system headers ---
//

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

//  Define M_PI in the case it's not defined in the math header file
#ifndef M_PI
#  define M_PI  3.14159265358979323846
#endif

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// --- Include OpenGL header files and helpers ---
//
//   The location of these files vary by operating system.  We've included
//     copies of open-soruce project headers in the "GL" directory local
//     this this "include" directory.
//

#ifdef __APPLE__  // include Mac OS X verions of headers
#  include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#  include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else // non-Mac OS X operating systems
#  include <GL/glew.h>
// #  include <GL/glut.h>
#  include <GL/freeglut.h>
#  include <GL/freeglut_ext.h>

#endif  // __APPLE__

// Define a helpful macro for handling offsets into buffer objects
#define BUFFER_OFFSET( offset )   ((GLvoid*) (offset))

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  --- Include our class libraries and constants ---
//

namespace Angel {

//  Helper function to load vertex and fragment shader files
GLuint InitShader( const char* vertexShaderFile,
           const char* fragmentShaderFile );

//  Defined constant for when numbers are too small to be used in the
//    denominator of a division operation.  This is only used if the
//    DEBUG macro is defined.
const GLfloat  DivideByZeroTolerance = GLfloat(1.0e-07);

//  Degrees-to-radians constant 
const GLfloat  DegreesToRadians = M_PI / 180.0;

}  // namespace Angel

#include "vec.h"
#include "mat.h"
#include "CheckError.h"

#define Print(x)  do { std::cerr << #x " = " << (x) << std::endl; } while(0)

//  Globally use our namespace in our example programs.
using namespace Angel;

#endif // __ANGEL_H__
```

### Update 3

It's working for me with the answer provided here but it's not with the `Angel.h`.

[image]

### Update 4

I found a way to do it with `Angel.h`. They way is to recode the `InitShader.cpp` to `InitShader.h` and then include for just one .cpp file:

```
/* sierpinski gasket using vertex buffer objects */

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "InitShader.h"
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  --- Angel.h ---
//
//   The main header file for all examples from Angel 6th Edition
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef __ANGEL_H__
#define __ANGEL_H__

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 
// --- Include system headers ---
//

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

//  Define M_PI in the case it's not defined in the math header file
#ifndef M_PI
#  define M_PI  3.14159265358979323846
#endif

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// --- Include OpenGL header files and helpers ---
//
//   The location of these files vary by operating system.  We've included
//     copies of open-soruce project headers in the "GL" directory local
//     this this "include" directory.
//

#ifdef __APPLE__  // include Mac OS X verions of headers
#  include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#  include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else // non-Mac OS X operating systems
#  include <GL/glew.h>
// #  include <GL/glut.h>
#  include <GL/freeglut.h>
#  include <GL/freeglut_ext.h>

#endif  // __APPLE__

// Define a helpful macro for handling offsets into buffer objects
#define BUFFER_OFFSET( offset )   ((GLvoid*) (offset))

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  --- Include our class libraries and constants ---
//

namespace Angel {

//  Helper function to load vertex and fragment shader files
//GLuint InitShader( const char* vertexShaderFile,
    //     const char* fragmentShaderFile );

//  Defined constant for when numbers are too small to be used in the
//    denominator of a division operation.  This is only used if the
//    DEBUG macro is defined.
const GLfloat  DivideByZeroTolerance = GLfloat(1.0e-07);

//  Degrees-to-radians constant 
const GLfloat  DegreesToRadians = M_PI / 180.0;

}  // namespace Angel

#include "vec.h"
#include "mat.h"
#include "CheckError.h"

#define Print(x)  do { std::cerr << #x " = " << (x) << std::endl; } while(0)

//  Globally use our namespace in our example programs.
using namespace Angel;

#endif // __ANGEL_H__



const int NumPoints = 5000;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
init( void )
{

    vec2 points[NumPoints];

    // Specifiy the vertices for a triangle
    vec2 vertices[3] = {
        vec2( -1.0, -1.0 ), vec2( 0.0, 1.0 ), vec2( 1.0, -1.0 )
    };

    // Select an arbitrary initial point inside of the triangle
    points[0] = vec2( 0.25, 0.50 );

    // compute and store N-1 new points
    for ( int i = 1; i < NumPoints; ++i ) {
        int j = rand() % 3;   // pick a vertex at random

        // Compute the point halfway between the selected vertex
        //   and the previous point
        points[i] = ( points[i - 1] + vertices[j] ) * 0.5;
    }

    // Create a vertex array object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    // Create and initialize a buffer object
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader21.glsl", "fshader21.glsl" );
    glUseProgram( program );

    // Initialize the vertex position attribute from the vertex shader
    GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( loc );
    glVertexAttribPointer( loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
                           BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );

    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); // white background
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
display( void )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );     // clear the window
    glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, NumPoints );    // draw the points
    glFlush();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    switch ( key ) {
    case 033:
        exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
        break;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA );
    glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );

    // If you are using freeglut, the next two lines will check if 
    // the code is truly 3.2. Otherwise, comment them out

     glutInitContextVersion( 3, 1 );
     glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );

    glutCreateWindow( "Sierpinski Gasket" );




    glewInit();

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: So it crashes on `glutInitContextVersion` or `glutInitContextProfile`? If `glutCreateWindow` runs, what does the function return?

Comment: Is your hardware actually capable of OpenGL 3.1?

Comment: It's likely that in this case, `glutCreateWindow` is failing to create an OpenGL context (which would be indicated by `glutCreateWindow` returning a zero).

Comment: If I comment out `glutCreateWindow`then there will be no stacktrace and also no window.

Comment: Have you tried adding glutInitWindowPosition( 0, 0 ); ?

Comment: Also, could you show your includes in the file with main()? //Edit :: I just noteced, that there is main() in other snippet - so to clarify : could you show how you include GL, glut, and glew?

Comment: @Losiowaty I get this runtime error: `Unhandled exception at 0x773DBDA1 in 6E test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.` There is no build error. I update the question with the includes which are available from the link where the example project is posted at the university. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Actually you didn't show them, all you include in this snippets is "Angel.h" - i will download the sample code later when I'll have access to computer.

Comment: I got it working now with help fro the new answer. I used the code from the answer with the math library and I don't use the Angel.h anymore. I just needed to get started and I think it was that I didn't build freeglut.dll and that freeglut.dll was missing but I could download it from http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/ which is working in VS 2012 on Windows 7. Now I want the 64-bit version to work, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workin' fine here:

[image: gasket screenshot]

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// header-only, http://glm.g-truc.net/
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

// GLSL shader program loader
struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* vert, const char* geom, const char* frag )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        if( vert ) AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert );
        if( geom ) AttachShader( prog, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, geom );
        if( frag ) AttachShader( prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE, len = 10;
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
        std::vector< char > log( len, 'X' );
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
        std::cerr << &log[0] << std::endl;
        exit( -1 );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

#define GLSL( version, shader )  "#version " #version "\n" #shader

const GLchar* vert = GLSL
(
    150,
    in vec4 vPosition;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = vPosition;
    }
);

const GLchar* frag = GLSL
(
    150,
    void main (void)
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    }
);

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int NumPoints = 5000;
void init( void )
{
    vec2 points[NumPoints];

    // Specifiy the vertices for a triangle
    vec2 vertices[3] =
    {
        vec2( -1.0, -1.0 ), vec2( 0.0, 1.0 ), vec2( 1.0, -1.0 )
    };

    // Select an arbitrary initial point inside of the triangle
    points[0] = vec2( 0.25, 0.50 );

    // compute and store N-1 new points
    for ( int i = 1; i < NumPoints; ++i )
    {
        int j = rand() % 3;   // pick a vertex at random

        // Compute the point halfway between the selected vertex
        //   and the previous point
        points[i] = ( points[i - 1] + vertices[j] ) / 2.0f;
    }

    // Create a vertex array object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    // Create and initialize a buffer object
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    GLuint program = Program::Load( vert, NULL, frag );
    glUseProgram( program );

    // Initialize the vertex position attribute from the vertex shader
    GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( loc );
    glVertexAttribPointer( loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)(0) );

    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); // white background
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void display( void )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );     // clear the window
    glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, NumPoints );    // draw the points
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    switch ( key )
    {
    case 033:
        exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
        break;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );

    // bumped to 3.2 (from 3.1) because your shaders are #version 150
    glutInitContextVersion( 3, 2 );
    glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );
    glutCreateWindow( "Sierpinski Gasket" );
    glewInit();

    std::cout << "OpenGL version: " << glGetString( GL_VERSION ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GLSL version: " << glGetString( GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION ) << std::endl;

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Make sure your GL implementation's version is actually >= 3.2 using something like the [OpenGL Extensions Viewer](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/).

I also recommend building the latest FreeGLUT (2.8.1 as of now) and GLEW (1.9.0) from source on the off-chance you're using pre-built binaries of unknown provenance.

Comment: Thank you. It's working for me in VS 2012 but as far as I understand this is the 32 bit version. I would like the 64-bit version to work.

Comment: You'll probably need 64-bit builds of FreeGLUT and GLEW then.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to refactor Angel's `InitShader.cpp` to `InitShader.h` and make a completely new project instead of converting the downlaoded project from VS 2010 to VS 2012.